# Jmeter multiple executions for each record from CSV

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I have a CSV of 100 records/rows, that I wish to execute (through a service) using JMeter.

Now, I want to execute each record 3 times (each after a delay of say, 5 secs), and do the same for all 100 records in the CSV.

How can I do so using JMeter?

Comment: You question is not clear , maybe an example of data and what should be dond could help

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't look to be hard implemented using jmeter's [standard components](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html).

1. Use properly configured [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) under [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to read all the entries from your csv-file.
2. In the same cycle use [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) set to required loops count - this will repeat your request N times with variables extracted from each csv-entry.
3. Under Loop Controller use suitable [sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), e.g. [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), to send your request with params from csv-entry.
4. Along with sampler use any [timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), e.g. [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer), to add delay after each request.

Schema may look like:

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads = 1   
Loop Count = 1
    . . .
    While Controller                 // this will iterate through your csv-file
    Condition = ${__javaScript("${var1}"!="",)}  // this will repeat until EOF
        CSV Data Set Config
        Filename = ...               // path to your csv file
        Variable Names = var1,...    // these are records read from file into pointed variables
        Delimiter = ,
        Recycle on EOF? = False
        Stop thread on EOF? = True
        Sharing Mode = Current thread group

        Loop Controller
        Loop Count = 3
            HTTP Request Sampler
            Constant Timer
            Thread Delay (in ms) = 5000
        . . .
```