# Running a thread group multiple times for all the values in a csv file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have recorded a series of 5 HTTP requests in a thread group (say TG). The response value of a request has to be sent as a parameter in next request, and so on till the last request is made.

To send the parameter in first request, I have created a csv file with unique values (say 1,2,3,4,5).

Now I want this TG to run for all the values read from the csv file (In above case, TG should start running for value 1, then value 2, till 5).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your CSV file looks like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

1. In the Thread Group set Loop Count to "Forever"
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element under the Thread Group and configure it as follows:

   - Filename: if file is in JMeter's **bin** folder - file name only. If in the other location - full path to CSV file
   - Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `parameter`
   - Recycle on EOF - `false`
   - Stop thread on OEF - `true`
   - Sharing mode - according to your scenario

You'll get something like:

[image: CSV Data Set Config Demo]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for more detailed explanation.

---

Another option is using [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T , it worked in a single try. So easy. I was heading in a completely wrong direction being new to JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

This method of creating individual request for each record will not be scalable for multiple records. There is  another scalable solution here - [Jmeter multiple executions for each record from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294680/jmeter-multiple-executions-for-each-record-from-csv/12330459)